# How to properly format bash commands output in HTML

Tags: bash, html

I was writing bash script that will daily send email to Management about the cluster status.

Content of shell sript.

```
ARG_EMAIL_TO="johndoe@domain.com"
ARG_EMAIL_FROM="root@db1.com"
ARG_EMAIL_SUBJECT="Cluster Status"

(
echo "To: ${ARG_EMAIL_TO}"
echo "From: ${ARG_EMAIL_FROM}"
echo "Subject: ${ARG_EMAIL_SUBJECT}"
echo "Mime-Version: 1.0"
echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset='utf-8'"
#echo "<body style="background-color:powderblue;">"
echo "<body>"
echo "<h1>Database Cluster Status at <span class="text-nowrap"><p><i><FONT COLOR="GREEN">`date`</FONT></i><p></span></h1>"
echo "<hr>"
echo "<p><FONT COLOR="BLUE">`pcs status`</FONT></p>"
echo "</body>"
) | sendmail -t
```

But when i receive email output is like this

[image]

also the "Database Cluster status at DATE and TIME" should be on same line.

sorry im not much familiar with html and css.

Comment: The `<p>` tag creates a block (unless you style it appropriately, but the easier solution is to just use a `<span>`): remove it to have the output of `date` on the same line as "Database Cluster Status at" (note, however, that this is off-topic on U&L). What else is not being displayed correctly? Are you expecting to see the output of `pcs status` spanning on several lines (instead of being a single long one)? If so, the on-topic part of your question would likely be about converting newlines into `</br>` tags (or something equivalent).

Comment: @fra-san, Thanks for reply, Yes "Database Cluster Status at and date" should be on same line. And the out put of command should span on multiple line.

Comment: @fra-san, i removed the <p> from script now  "Database Cluster Status at and date" are on same line. Now remaining is output of pcs status command which should span multiple lines

Comment: for status line try using `<pre>` and `</pre>` inside `<font ...>...</font>`

Comment: Appreciate a lot now i got the desired output. Thanks